# How to make HBASE Durable and Get Notification From Memstore before flush

Tags: hbase

I am using HBase with S3 as data storage on EMR.  I found that when the EMR cluster is crashed the data in the memstore and in WAL is not recovered.  EMR stores data in EBS, and when cluster is crashed EBS is gone.  Therefore we decided to put the WAL on S3.  But  writes to S3 are done asynchronously in large chunks therefore if the cluster crashes when the WAL is in cache it is not recovered.  We want to use Hbase as durable storage.  We want to know how should we resolve this.

1. How do we keep track of last updated record in Hbase.
2. How do we know that the update of data from Memstore is not successful.
3. How should we configure and tune HBase to achieve durability.
4. If WAL is not durable across clusters then can I write in the HFile directly without calling WAL for every single event.  I know we can do this for batch load but how about small load or every single writes.

Comment: Regarding your question #4 -- you can configure this at an individual write level or at a table level as well. For individual writes, you can use Mutation.setDurability() with one of the options there being to skip WAL. At a table level, you can set that option during table creation time with TableDescriptor. You can also use the combination of the two -- set a certain 'default' option at table-level, and then optionally adjust it for a given individual write to that table.

Comment: Thanks @VS_FF what is the performance impact of skipping the WAL for every single event.  Is it recommended approach?  Only reason I want to skip WAL is durability.

Comment: Well that won't improve durability for sure -- only make it worse! Since you are instructing HBase to not write anything to WAL, the updates you've done that haven't been flushed to disk will not be 'replayed' when the system comes back online. I thought you were looking to skip WAL just to speed up the performance (and frankly in my experience I haven't seen much improvement in performance that way). MAYBE what you should look into instead is more of a managed approach to flushing Memstore. That way your updates will be put do disk more frequently?

Comment: @VS_FF actually we wanted to save money by using S3 as durable storage.  Since Hbase with S3 as data storage is supported only with EMR we are planning to use EMR.   So if we use WAL we can store WAL in HDFS or in S3.  If we use HDFS then if the cluster crashes the WAL data in HDFS will not be recovered.  So we thought we can use S3 for data storage, but S3 has no concept of append it performs batch update.  We want to use HBase as durable storage we are trying to figure out how.

Comment: I thought if we write to HFile directly we can have durability but that has cost as well.  Not sure if HBase can be used as a OnLine database.

Comment: @VS_FF can we manage Memstore flushes?  Can we get callback from Memstore about when it flushes data to HFile?  I am thinking if we know when Memstore flushed the data last before the cluster crashes then we can replay the events that was not flushed.

Comment: I don't use amazon so can't get into specifics there. But as for HBase in general, you SHOULD think of it as durable. The fact that your cluster crashes perhaps suggests that maybe it's too small or misconfigured? I would suggest not spending too much time on such minutiae as WAL etc. and instead just trying to configure and size the cluster properly. And even if it crashes, it SHOULD recover the lost data from WAL. Maybe dig through the logs and see why it's not happening (or maybe it simply takes longer than you you gave it time?) Can't help there..

Comment: On memstore flushes, I haven't done that before myself, but hope you can look around. It was more of a suggestion as to what else to look for.